# Can I allow only certain specific strings to be inputted for a table in Oracle 10G?

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, check-constraints

```
CREATE TABLE trial (
    phone_number NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY;
    name VARCHAR2(20)
)
```

In this table, I want a constraint such that, name inputted should be only 'trial','experiment' or 'test'.

Comment: You have several answers all suggesting a check constraint.  However, if your list of 'acceptable' strings is likely to change, you might want to considers putting them in a reference table, so that you won't have to be changing the definition of the check constraint.

Comment: Also, as a side observation, please note that NUMBER is not the proper type for PHONE_NUMBER.  Even though we call it a phone _number_, it is not a number in the mathematical sense, which is what NUMBER is for.  A phone number is just a character string that by current convention uses only numeric characters.  But look at your phone dial/keypad.  See those letters?  They did not get introduced to enable text messaging.  If you declare your phone_number as NUMBER, then enter a phone number of '0123456789', you will lose that leading zero, which is actually a critical part of the _number_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the `CHECK` constraint as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE trial  
ADD CONSTRAINT name_CHK CHECK (NAME IN ('trial','experiment','test'));
```

If you don't want the null values in the name then you can also use `NOT NULL` constraint on the `name` column.

While creating the table, you can use the Constraint inside it as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE trial (
    phone_number NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY;
    name VARCHAR2(20) not null,
    CONSTRAINT name_CHK CHECK (NAME IN ('trial','experiment','test')
);
```

Comment: How can I use this constraint while creating the table?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CHECK` constraint:

```sql
CREATE TABLE trial (
    phone_number NUMBER(5)
                 CONSTRAINT trial__phone_number__pk PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR2(20)
                 NOT NULL
                 CONSTRAINT trial__name__ck CHECK (
                   name IN ( 'trial', 'experiment', 'test' )
                 )
);
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO trial ( phone_number, name )
SELECT 1, 'trial' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'experiment' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'test' FROM DUAL;
```

Works but:

```sql
INSERT INTO trial ( phone_number, name ) VALUES ( 4, 'not valid' );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ORA-02290: check constraint (SCHEMA_NAME.TRIAL__NAME__CK) violated
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0b2f2851c627ffdb75588aebeffddbd0)*

Answer (score 0):

It is a `check` constraint:

```
SQL> create table trial
  2    (phone_number number(5) primary key,
  3     name         varchar2(20) constraint ch_tri_nam check
  4                                 (name in ('trial', 'experiment', 'test'))
  5    );

Table created.

SQL> insert into trial (phone_number, name) values (1, 'trial');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into trial (phone_number, name) values (1, 'what');
insert into trial (phone_number, name) values (1, 'what')
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02290: check constraint (SCOTT.CH_TRI_NAM) violated


SQL>
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a trigger whose message is more descriptive (check constraint only says that it is violated; in a trigger, you can create your own message).

```
SQL> create table trial
  2    (phone_number number(5) primary key,
  3     name         varchar2(20)
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_trial
  2    before insert or update on trial
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if nvl(:new.name, :old.name) not in ('trial', 'experiment', 'test') then
  6       raise_application_error(-20000, 'Invalid name; allowed values are: trial, experiment, test');
  7    end if;
  8  end;
  9  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into trial (phone_number, name) values (1, 'trial');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into trial (phone_number, name) values (1, 'what');
insert into trial (phone_number, name) values (1, 'what')
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Invalid name; allowed values are: trial, experiment, test
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TRIAL", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.TRG_BIU_TRIAL'


SQL>
```